# How to increment variables inside argument?

Tags: python, variables, increment

In the code below I want to creat a string list and I pass a variable *min* to a method as an argument:

```
max_list = [1 , 2 , 3]
min = 0
output = ["{a} + {b}".format(a=min, b=max) for max in max_list]
```

However, I want to increment min every time I generate a list object.
Is there a python way to achieve the same result of ++ operator? Apparently, I can't use min++ in this case as it is python code.

Expected Result:

```
['0 + 1', '1 + 2', '2 + 3']
```

Comment: please share your expected output

Comment: You should not use min or max as your variable names, as these are python reserved keywords. try to make it a practise

Comment: Thank you, I will pay attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `min` and `max` are unfortunate variable names in python, as they shadow built-in `min` and `max` functions. As for increasing by 1 you might harness [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) following way:

```
import itertools
max_list = [1 , 2 , 3]
mn = itertools.count(0)
output = ["{a} + {b}".format(a=next(mn), b=mx) for mx in max_list]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['0 + 1', '1 + 2', '2 + 3']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, plus the answer above, so I can use enumerate and itertools.count plus next to achieve the the same result of ++ in C. But allow me to be greedy here, is there a simpler way to do this? like min++ in C for every iterate?

Comment: @heihei: I do not know that, as you do not explained this I assumed you were meaning `++` in JavaScript sense. Independently from that it might be useful for you to know that what did you used is called in python [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't share your expected output so this may not be what you wanted, but...

```
max_list = [1, 2, 3]
output = [f"{min} + {max}" for min, max in enumerate(max_list)]
print(output)
```

**Output:**
`['0 + 1', '1 + 2', '2 + 3']`

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly the result i want, so what i understand is there is no "simple way"? like ++ in C?

Comment: you mean in python?,  yes

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.8 you can use [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=`. But since the increment will occur before the return of the expression result like `++min`, you need to initialize `min` to `-1`

```
max_list = [1 , 2 , 3]
min = -1
output = ["{a} + {b}".format(a=(min := min + 1) , b=max) for max in max_list]
```